# Wordpress Menu for Social Icons

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to use the wordpress custom menu to allow users to link their social media sites easily. So far I set up a wordpress menu "Social Icons" in my functions.php theme file and am using the custom menu widget to place it on the site. This is the html wordpress generated for the menu and widget

```
<div class="menu-social-icons-container">
<ul id="menu-social-icons" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-73" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-73"><a href="http://facebook">Facebook</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-74" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-74"><a href="http://twitter">Twitter</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-76" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-76"><a href="http://instagram">Instagram</a></li>
<li id="menu-item-77" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-77"><a href="http://youtube">Youtube</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I'm assuming the id "menu-social-icons" is due to either the theme location or menu name I created so IF the id is based upon that I could use this method to allow users to link up their social media icons. Will the id "menu-social-icons" be the same for any user that uses this theme, or is it a generated id like "menu-item-73" in the li.

If it will be the same, I am trying to style the nth child a elements to backgrounds of the icons but I'm confused as to which selectors to use in css because for example if I use

```
ul#menu-social-icons li a:link:nth-child(1){
background-img:url(images/facebook.png);
}

ul#menu-social-icons li a:link:nth-child(2){
background-img:url(images/twitter.png);
}
```

ect

I don't get anything

What selectors do I need to use to style achieve this?

Comment: try with `ul#menu-social-icons li:nth-child(1) a{`

Comment: i also added a example on the the answer with the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider to this example http://jsfiddle.net/jogesh_pi/d85Ae/

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#link1">link1</a></li>
   <li><a href="link2">link2</a></li>
   <li><a href="link3">link3</a></li>
   <li><a href="link4">link4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul li:nth-child(1) a{ color: #ff0000; }
ul li:nth-child(2) a{ color: green; }
ul li:nth-child(3) a{ color: #ff9900; }
```

**Note:** Make sure about the path of images that you want to implement on the menus

Comment: thanks, any idea about the ID? will it change if the theme is activated by another user on another host?

Comment: don't target to the ID in menus, it vary according to host. take a look on this link http://sevenspark.com/how-to/how-to-add-a-custom-class-to-a-wordpress-menu-item, i know its third party according to your plugin, but this will give you a idea to achieve what you want.